# Deploying MVC web site to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, azure

I'm getting an error when I deploy a fresh MVC 3 web app to Azure. Though the site appears to work there are role initialisation errors meaning that the deployment from VS2010 never completes. (See output below.)

I suspect the Mindscape.Lightspeed.Web assembly is dependent on MVC 2. But I thought the following config section would override it.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

You can simulate this with an Azure project by uninstalling MVC 2 from your development system and then running in the development fabric.

How can I fix this?

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 201 : 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1001b7f1\d3c78bbf\assembly\dl3\d2532ce7\a08fd830_9d4bcd01\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.DLL'
Role entrypoint could not be created:
System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = DiscoveryOne\scott
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/scott/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Teto.Azure/Teto.Azure/csx/Debug/roles/Teto.Web/approot/bin
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Teto.Azure\Teto.Azure\csx\Debug\roles\Teto.Web\approot\bin
Calling assembly : Mindscape.LightSpeed.Web, Version=4.0.1351.20441, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360c8f37b466ebb2.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/scott/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Teto.Azure/Teto.Azure/csx/Debug/roles/Teto.Web/approot/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

 ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
The program '[1564] WaIISHost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[1564] WaIISHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly redirect should be fine, but don't forget that you might need to configure it in multiple files:

- Web.config
- Views\Web.config
- WaIISHost.exe.config

You'll need to make sure you modify both Web.config files. If you're calling that LightSpeed assembly from your **WebRole.cs** file, I suggest you create a new file called **WeIISHost.exe.config**, add the redirect and set it the Copy to Output Directory to always. This is required because the WebRole now uses [full IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx).

[image]

Comment: I did this but for a while I forgot to include the xmlns attribute on the assemblyBinding element. Forcing it to fail semi-silently.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure Lightspeed is configured to run in Partial Trust mode?

[http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/13/the-dynamic-duo-lightspeed-azure](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/13/the-dynamic-duo-lightspeed-azure/)

Comment: It's set to Full Trust so should be OK. At this stage, the linking of the LightSpeed Web assembly seems to be causing the problem.